# Gson and Active Android: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?

Tags: android, gson, activeandroid

I'm using Gson to serialize an Active Android model.  The model class contains only primitives, and Gson should have no issues serializing it with the default settings.  However, when I try, I get the error:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: <MyClass>. Forgot to register a type adapter?`

I would really rather not write a type adapter for every one of my model classes, how can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured it out. Of course, Active Android's base model class is adding fields that cannot be serialized by default.  Those fields can be ignored using Gson's `excluedFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` option, as follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String json = gson.toJson(new Book());
```

Modify the class with the `@Expose` annotation to indicate which fields should be serialized:

```
@Table(name = "Foo")
public class Foo extends Model {

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String name;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "Sort")
    public int sort;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Where to set Gson setting in application for ActiveAndroid like Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

Answer (score 15):

an easier way is to initialize your Gson as below to prevent serializing Final,Transient or Static fields

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();
```

Comment: This is perfect solution. Above solutions make "mId" null so model.delete(); causes null pointer exception.

Comment: Where to set Gson setting in application for ActiveAndroid like Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

Comment: I am getting the following error after following the GLee's approach. Did anyone else get this: Failed to invoke public consturctor with no args

Comment: @AmrataB This error is raised when you did not create a no-argument constructor for the class you are serializing.

Comment: @medhi  Unclear whether the Gson can/should be used as a singleton, or the GsonBuilder().. should be (and reused to .create() ). Is the Gson reusable?